# How can we compute the quantity $hc/e$ vs gauss and centimeter

Tags: units

In some textbook, authors mention that the amount of $hc/e$ equals to $4.136 \,\text{gauss}\times cm^2$. Where, $h$ and $c$ are Plank's constant and the speed of light respectively. Positive $e$ is the absolute charge of an electron.

In order to calculate directly the above amount, I have inserted $hc=1240 eV\times nm$. Then I remove $e$ from the numerator and denominator.

After that, I replaced $V$(volt) in SI units as $kg\times m^2\times s^{-3}\times A^{-1}$ and regards to Tesla in SI units is as $kg\times A^{-1} \times s^{-2}$ also 1 Tesla is $10^4$ gauss, but I could not reach to 4.136 gauss $\times cm^2$!!! How can I calculate by hand the amount of $hc/e$?

Comment: It is fundamental flux quanta special in landau levels

Comment: Sorry, I messed up. The units fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the correct value of $hc/e$ in CGS units is $4.136\times10^{-7}\,\text{gauss}\cdot\text{cm}^2$, not $4.136\,\text{gauss}\cdot\text{cm}^2$.

Second, sometimes formulas involving electromagnetic quantities are actually different in CGS and SI units. (Think about what the Lorentz force looks like in both systems, for example.) In this case, $hc/e$ is a magnetic flux in CGS, but that same magnetic flux is just $h/e$ in SI! (If you don’t believe me, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_flux_quantum.)

Since the formula isn’t even the same in the two systems, you definitely want to avoid converting units between the two systems like you were trying to do.

In CGS, we can evaluate $hc/e$ using the values of $h$, $c$, and $e$ in CGS units, namely

$$h=6.626\times10^{-27}\,\text{erg}\cdot\text{s}$$
$$c=2.998\times10^{10}\,\text{cm}\cdot\text{s}^{-1}$$
$$e=4.803\times10^{-10}\,\text{esu}.$$

These values give the correct result,

$$hc/e=4.136\times10^{-7}\,\text{gauss}\cdot\text{cm}^2.$$

We can also evaluate $h/e$ in SI units using

$$h=6.626\times10^{-34}\,\text{J}\cdot\text{s}$$
$$e=1.602\times10^{-19}\,\text{C}$$

to get

$$h/e=4.136\times10^{-15}\,\text{T}\cdot\text{m}^2$$

and then use the fact that 1 tesla is $10^4$ gauss and 1 meter is $10^2$ cm.

The general lesson to be learned is: When a book uses CGS for its formulas, work entirely in CGS units.